# Is the use of 'a garden' in this sentence correct?

Tags: articles

> *John [seeing Anthony and Barbara on a sidewalk]*
>   *John:* Hi, guys. Good evening!
>   *Barbara:* Good evening. How're things going?
>   *John:* Never been better. I've just finished my gym class an hour ago. What about you guys?
>   *Barbara:* We have planted some roses in **a** garden.
>   *John:* Which one? The East Park?
>   *Barbara:* Yeah, that one.
>   ...

I've made that dialog up, and now I wonder that
do I have to change that article *"a"* to *"the"*? Or I can leave it like that?

Comment: I'd say it draws attention to *garden* as new information.  It strikes me as slightly unexpected, but not wrong.  It fits with the following question asked by John.  What I **would** do is remove the perfect auxiliary *have*, along with its cliticized friend *'ve*.

Comment: Not only do I agree with @snailboat that *Barbara's response* should not use the present perfect (but rather the simple past), but I'd go further to say that the contracted *I've* in *John's* preceding line is not only uncalled for, but it's completely wrong. You should either change that to read ***I've just finished** my gym class.* or ***I finished** my gym class **an hour ago***. If you use a reference to a specific point in time in the same sentence, then it should be in the simple past tense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe it or not, such a tiny change makes a big difference. In this case, it's *a*, but that's an uncommon use. It's not at all incorrect though.

Most people mean to say *planted some roses in **the (my/our)** garden*.

That means that this person planted some roses in **their** garden, or in a **specific** garden that these particular speakers could mutually refer to as *the garden*, like, say, a community or church garden for example. It's more likely the former.

When you say *planted some rose in **a** garden*, you mean that you just planted flowers in some unspecified, random, or generic garden.

It's not at all incorrect to use the indefinite article as I've done in the above sentence, if that is in fact what you mean; but, as I've said, it's an uncommon usage, especially given the context.

I'd probably revise it. But if you do, you'd have to end the dialog at that point, as the rest would be unnecessary.

Comment: Suppose that there are more than one community gardens nearby (I believe that it is possible in some country, maybe Germany), can I still use "the garden"? Or in this multiple community gardens case, I need to use "a garden"?

Comment: Yes you can! If you were to do that, that would still make the last lines relevant because, *the garden* is still generic, even though it refers to a specific garden. If that's what you mean, then go with *the*. If the person were referring to something known, the last lines would obviously be uncalled for

Comment: I agreed with you up to the last sentence. If someone referred to "the garden", that indicates they have one particular garden in mind. But someone listening does not necessarily know what garden that is, and so might reasonably ask "The garden? Which garden?" Now if earlier in the conversation they had said something that would make clear which garden they were referring to, that would be different. Like, "We were at Bob's house." "Oh, what were you doing there?" "We planted roses in the garden." The clear inference then would be that "the garden" refers to the garden at Bob's house. ...

Comment: ... I suppose it's possible that Bob's house has more than one garden. Etc.

Comment: @Jay Normally, if someone were to say *What did you do today?*, and I'd responded with something like *I planted flowers in the garden*, the other party would assume that I planted them in **my** garden, even if they didn't know I had one. That's just common parlance in the US.

Comment: @JohnQPublic Sure. Maybe we're just quibbling over what you meant by "unnecessary". If you said you planted flowers "in the garden", I'd generally assume that you meant the garden at your own house. But it would not be unreasonable to ask which garden if I thought there was some doubt. e.g. if you had just mentioned being at a friend's house, I might wonder if you meant her garden or your own garden. My point is just that while we might generally fill in assumptions, depending on context the sentence could be ambiguous and it is not absurd to ask for clarification.

Comment: @Jay I won't detract from your arguments, because you are proposing some very specific scenarios for which these words would not be redundant; but, I'd just like to point out that I'm speaking very generally. There are any number of possibilities that would make the final two lines still relevant, but in the **most basic of contexts**, they **may not** be necessary.

Comment: @JohnQPublic No argument there.